# How do you adjust table cell size?

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I want to change the size of my table cell to be smaller in height. The first cell has an image of 300px width. I'd like the second cell to have a height of 100px. I've tried html solutions like `<td height="10">` but that hasn't worked. What I'm looking to do is have an image on the left and a text block on the right.

```
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <img id="plattOverlook" src="images/Scenic/plattOverlook.jpg"/> </td>
            <td style="background: white"> This is an overlook. </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: And what do you mean by setting the height of the other cell? What would it *mean* to have cells with different heights on the same row? Why do you mention the width of the image (which should be immaterial) but not its height?

Comment: That ``<table>`` is meaningless here. Keep the ``<img/>`` tag, add a ``<p>...</p>`` around the text, and position them using CSS ``float`` property on ``display:inline-block;``.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple table adjacent table data cells will always be the same height unless you use 
rowspan=*

Have a look at this page (about half way down) - 
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/_TD_COLSPAN.html

You will have to use rowspan for the image. 
Other wise I don't think there's any possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowspan`.

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/10z7ya28/

Answer (score -1):

```
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave I'm new at this site